# NSMutableDictionary objectForKey returns null with correct key

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Im having a really weird problem with NSDictionary, take a look at the code and the console output and see for yourself.

```
for (int y = 0; y < self.tileProperties.allKeys.count; ++y) {

//I go over all the keys in my NSDictionary,self.tileProperties.

       NSString *string = [self.tileProperties.allKeys objectAtIndex:y];

        NSLog(@"Keys is %@",string);
        NSLog(@"Objects in Array %@",[self.tileProperties objectForKey:string]);
    }


   NSLog(@"Object in Array 2 %@",[self.tileProperties objectForKey:@"496"]);
```

This is what the console outputs.

```
2016-09-12 17:23:00.822 GreatGrimBeta[1043:130572] Keys is 496
2016-09-12 17:23:00.822 GreatGrimBeta[1043:130572] Objects in Array {
fire = 7;
}
2016-09-12 17:23:00.823 GreatGrimBeta[1043:130572] Object in Array 2 (null)
```

Why am i getting null from the same key I just used in the for loop?

thank you for the help!

Comment: `for (id key in self.tileProperties) { NSLog(@"Key desc: [%@] class: %@", key, [key class]); }` The key probably isn't a string; alternatively, it might have whitespace.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I got this from the console   Key desc: [496] class: __NSCFNumber

Comment: Well, there you go. It's an `NSNumber`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell OMG!! lol wow thats crazy! i would of never guessed that was the issue!!! thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Answer with the help of JoshCaswell

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:496];
NSLog(@"Object in Array 2 %@",[self.tileProperties objectForKey:num]);

2016-09-12 18:14:43.217 GreatGrimBeta[1156:149732] LOOK {
    fire = 7;
}
```

Comment: FYI - you can write that 1st line as: `NSNumber *num = @496;`. And the 2nd line as: `NSLog(@"Object in array 2 %@", self.tileProperties[num]);`.

Comment: Or all in one line: `NSLog(@"Object in array 2 %@", self.tileProperties[@496]);`.

Comment: @rmaddy I did just that! ink you!